# -moz-transform-origin not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

This works in webkit, but for some reason the -moz-transform isn't working in FF any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/KtCSy/

```
<img id="heart" width="47" height="42"  src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/d95e8df8385d7c4696d1211e8d8f7e64/tumblr_mm5q9hi3iF1rgpyeqo1_500.png" alt="love">

#heart {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
  -webkit-animation: Pulse 2s ease-out infinite;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Pulse {
  0%   {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50%   {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
     -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All your `-moz-` rules are kept inside a `-webkit-` `@` rule, so only WebKit will see them (and ignore them)

Comment: Quentin is right. Your -moz rules are not parsed by Firefox since the @-webkit-keyframes Pulse at-rule is treated as an unknown rule and discarded. This should work in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/KtCSy/3/